# Kibana server is not ready - unable to retrieve information fron elastic nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elk

I have ELK stack which was running so far using docker-compose.
I'm trying to port that docker compose to kubernetes and while I know this is not the desired way of installing ELK on k8s, I have few days to test the approach and think about issues/required changes.

I was able to bring up the pods and they are running but when I access Kibana in my web browser, I get error that:
`Kibana server is not ready et`
Using chrome developer console, I can see some error but I dont think they are related to this issue.

`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

and
`GET http://20.4.187.154:5601/internal/interactive_setup/status 503 (Service Unavailable)`

I'm able to curl elasticsearch host from my Kibana pod  using elastic user and his password:

```
kibana@tone-kibana:~/logs$ curl -u elastic:somepassword-XGET tone-elasticsearch:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 10,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 5,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 66.66666666666666
}
kibana@tone-kibana:~/logs$
```

I can do that also with using `kibana_system` user so this should not be a problem I think.

My `kibana.yaml' and` elasticsearch.yaml`

```
server.name: tone-kibana
server.host: 0.0.0.0

elasticsearch.hosts: [ "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}" ]
monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
server.basePath: /app/kibana

# X-Pack security credentials

elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "${KIBANA_PASSWORD}"
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: "/usr/share/kibana/config/certs/ca/ca.crt"
```

elasticsearch:

```
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    ---
    ## Default Elasticsearch configuration from Elasticsearch base image.
    ## https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/docker/src/docker/config/elasticsearch.yml
    #
    cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    node.name: "${SVC_ELASTIC}"

    ## X-Pack settings
    ## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack.html
    #
    xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic 
    xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: false

    ## Security
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/${SVC_ELASTIC}/${SVC_ELASTIC}.key"
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/${SVC_ELASTIC}/${SVC_ELASTIC}.crt"
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca/ca.crt"
    xpack.security.authc:
      anonymous:
        username: anonymous_user
        roles: metrics
        authz_exception: true

    # backup repo
    path.repo: ["/backup"]
```

```
[2023-07-28T08:19:10.792+00:00][INFO ][plugins.ruleRegistry] Installing common resources shared between all indices
[2023-07-28T08:19:10.832+00:00][INFO ][plugins.cloudSecurityPosture] Registered task successfully [Task: cloud_security_posture-stats_task]
[2023-07-28T08:19:11.354+00:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.config] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Linux Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.
[2023-07-28T08:19:11.395+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [cluster:monitor/nodes/info] is unauthorized for user [anonymous_user] with effective roles [metrics], this action is granted by the cluster privileges [monitor,manage,all]
[2023-07-28T08:19:11.857+00:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser executable: /usr/share/kibana/x-pack/plugins/screenshotting/chromium/headless_shell-linux_x64/headless_shell
/usr/local/bin/import-patterns.sh;Waiting for kibana to come up...
/usr/local/bin/import-patterns.sh;OK - Kibana is up
```

That `connection refused` error is worrying me but I don't know why this is happening
Is this because below part of `elasticsearch.yml`?

```
    xpack.security.authc:
      anonymous:
        username: anonymous_user
        roles: metrics
        authz_exception: true
```

I thought that because `kibana_system` user is set in `kibana.yaml`, it will be used instead of this anonymous_user.

Comment: Enabling Inline execution is a serious security threat, hence it is by default restricted by ELK stack. It is an expected error as mentioned [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/55997#issuecomment-840731020) and it should not be effecting any functionalities. Check the elastic and kibana pod logs for any other error which might be preventing you from accessing the dashboard. There is one more issue stating that some browsers doesn't support their latest version for kibana go through this [link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/30468#issuecomment-1631131951) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a very "stupid" issue. Problem was, kibana was expecting kibana.yml file, not a kibana.yaml file... Because of that, it was authenticating anonymous user, instead of kibana_system.